# Javascript console not working if Google Chrome is started from OS X terminal

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, console.log

Since I am working locally with d3.js, I need to launch Google Chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` option. To do this, I start Chrome from the OS X terminal, as follows:

`open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files`

However, it seems that this prevents the javascript console from working correctly. `console.log()` does not print anything anymore. I suppose the output is redirected elsewhere when Chrome is started this way.

Is there a way to launch Chrome with options and still have the console working as usual?

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same problem. The solution for me was to uncheck the "Set locale environment variables on startup" checkbox in the terminal settings.
After that, restart the terminal and google chrome.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-chrome-developer-tools/rC9_0sIejvs